# why is my "while" loop not ending when it is evaluating a variable returned from a function?

Tags: python, function, recursion, while-loop

I have done a few tests and i every time i put a function that returns the variable or a standard value depending on an if statement (that checks the value of the variable) inside a loop that checks whether it returned the constant (ending if the constant is not returned) the loop never ends. Could someone please explain why?

heres my code:

```
def check(n, count):
  maxCount = count;
  if (n < 10):
    return count, maxCount
  
  numberList = [int(i) for i in str(n)]
  total = 1
  for j in numberList:
    total = j * total
  
  count = count + 1
  return count, 9999


  for l in range(26, 27):
    count, maxCount = check(l, 0)
    while maxCount == 9999:
      count, maxCount = check(l, count)
    print (maxCount)
```

If there is a better way to do this then I am all ears.

Comment: the check function returns count and 9999 always and 9999 is assigned to the maxCount always .. it will never finish .. change 9999 to something else or maxCount to something else

Comment: What is the `check()` function supposed to do?

Comment: Please extract a [mcve] and provide that as part of your question. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: @hedgie It checks the multiplacative persistence of a given number - check out numberphile's video titled "whats special about the number 277777788888899" if you are interested in the maths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, its pretty simple actually. Looks like in the check function you are returning `9999` for all values of `n >= 10`.

In your for loop the range that you have is between 26 and 27 which means that the second value that the `check` function will return inside this for loop will be `9999`.

And, in your while loop you are checking if this is equal `9999` and hence it will go to an infinite loop as shown below.

```
check(26, 0) returns count, 9999 initially
inside while loop:
check(26, count) returns updated_count, 9999
next iteration of while loop:
check(26, count) returns updated_count, 9999
next iteration of while loop:
check(26, count) returns updated_count, 9999
next iteration of while loop:
check(26, count) returns updated_count, 9999
.
.
.
.
.
```

This is why the while loop never ends and it becomes an infinite loop.

If you are a new coder, always try to write the loop variables down to start with, as I have done above and that is some basic debugging. Obviously as you learn more you will also learn about Debug Tools.

Comment: Thanks, I added 1 word and changed another and now its all working:)

Comment: Happy to help :) Cheers